# sunspot-solr: How to exclude search results that include any given word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot-solr, websolr

I have a Ruby on Rails application which uses solr. I use sunspot gem for that. I also use websolr for the production environment.

I know we can do fulltext searching with sunspot solr. But I also want to be able to exclude any hit (and eventually result) that has a given word.

Example class:

```
class Article
    searchable do
        text :title
        text :content
    end
end
```

Now, I want to search for the articles that include **"Obama"** in its content but also want to exclude ones that **also** have the word **"Lady Gaga"**. I know I can apply reject block on returned array of results but I want to handle this situation on Solr level.

Hope I stated my problem clearly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Fulltext-search

> A small subset of the normal boolean query syntax is parsed: in particular, well-matched quotation marks can be used to demarcate phrases, and *the + and - operators can be used to require or exclude words respectively*

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: this seems to br the solution but can you give an example usage? I couldn't use fulltext "Obama" -"Lady Gaga" or fulltext "Obama -Lady Gaga".

Comment: Well, in particular I've tried `Job.search { keywords "java -'software engineer'" }` and it seems to work on our app.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `adjust_solr_params` to use edismax with a negating clause.

```
Article.search do
  fulltext params[:q]
  adjust_solr_params do |solr|
    solr['defType'] = 'edismax'
    solr['q'] += %( -"some phrase to exclude")
  end
end
```

Not the most obvious approach, certainly not documented, *and* I haven't tested it, but it should work. Hopefully future versions of Sunspot will support edismax more natively.

Comment: Regarding adjust_solr_params method: "This method is unsupported and your mileage may vary." from https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sunspot/2.1.1/Sunspot%2FDSL%2FAdjustable:adjust_solr_params